# Adapt script to work with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, button

I have a script which opens a book when the user clicks a button. How can I make this work for three buttons? Currently only the first button works.

This code is in the `head` of the document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_custom_form() {
    product_id = document.getElementById("product-size-selection").value;
    if(product_id) {
        var params = "";
        // call and api library function to go to the software
        Pixfizz.createBook(product_id, params)
    } else {
        alert("Please select a product from the dropdown");
    }
}
</script>
```

and this code is in the `body`

```
<div style="display: block; text-align: center;">
    <select id="product-size-selection" name="product-size-selection" style="margin: auto; font-family: formata; color: white; background-color: grey;">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose Your Size</option>
        <option value="ACRYLICCOMBOCOVER6X8:6X8COMBOCOVER">6x8 Custom Acrylic Cover</option>
        <option value="CUSTOMCOVER8X6:8X6FULLCOVER">8x6 Custom Satin Cover</option>
        <option value="ACRYLICCOMBOCOVER8X8:8X8COMBOCOVER">8x8 Custom Acrylic Cover</option>
        <option value="ACRYLICCOMBOCOVER9X12:9X12COMBOCOVER">9x12 Custom Acrylic Cover</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <button onclick="javascript:submit_custom_form()">Create My Album</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to access the buttons through `document.getElementById`.

Unfortunately, the `id` attribute can only be applied to a single DOM element. This means if you have the same id defined in more than one HTML tag, you're not going to get the expected result.

Change it to a class selector and use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: what would i change in the body for that to work as well I tried changing
<select id="product-size-selection" to <select class="product-size-selection" but that didn't work

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is going to return an array of all the DOM nodes of that class.  This means you'll want to iterate over this array and look up the values on each one.